# Cannot open webpage after connected to Wi-Fi/3G

Tags: browser, internet

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Ace phone. I'm connected to the Wi-Fi, but cannot go online. It always shows "webpage cannot open". Whatsapp, Twitter, Instagram, and Google Play are working fine.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Browser apps cache and data via the manage apps menu?

Comment: What do you mean *cannot go online* and Twitter working fine. You mean only your browser is not working?